# How to interpret AR(1) parameter estimates from SAS time series forecasting system?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, sas, autoregressive

I am attempting to fit an AR(1) model to some synthetic data, to become more familiar with the time series forecasting system in SAS. In my understanding, such a model would be of the form X(t) = c + bX(t-1) + e(t), where e is some error term, c a (possibly absent) constant, and b a damping coefficient applied to the previous value of the series. But I'm having trouble reconciling this with the results I get from fitting such a model (not worried at this stage if it's a good fit) using SAS:

[image]

From this, I'd naively assume that my model is X(t) = 0.94659 + 0.71130 X(t-1), under the assumption that the noise is mean 0. But the 'predictions' SAS is giving for the data set values (which I'm assuming are fitted values from its model at that time step) don't match this:

[image]

Since X(1) is conveniently 0, it's clear my interpretation of the model is wrong, given an X(2) prediction of 0.2733. So, how do I translate the parameters I have into the form I expect; or if it's my understanding of AR(1) models that's faulty, what should I be trying to parse this as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation shall be:
X(t) = (1-b)*mu + b* X(t-1)

Therefore you will get for X2 = (1-0.7113)*0.94659 = 0.2733

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If I then went to AR(2), it'd be something like (1-b_1-b_2)mu +b_1X(t-1) +b_2X(t-2) ?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Thank you! I was badly misinterpreting what they meant by 'intercept'.